# Check if string contains any instance of a word in an array with PHP

Tags: php, validation, filter

I have a simple form that needs extra validation. I have an array of banned words, which if any are present, the form submission fails.

I've been able to get it to work if the *only word* in the input is banned. However if it contains normal words and a banned word, the form submission goes through.

I do know the banned words db is working fine, as I have test code to output all of them

This is what only works if a banned term is the only word/string in there.

```
// array of banned words to filter; comes from DB
$disallowed_terms = Array();

$disallowed = $ww_mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM nl_filters");
$disallowed->bind_param('s', $Filter);
$disallowed->execute();

$s_result = $disallowed->get_result();

// check each input for banned words
while ($row = $s_result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $disallowed_terms[] = $row;

     // only wrote this for $sprequests for testing
     // strpos() doesn't seem to the right method here
     $sprequests_check = strpos($sprequests,$disallowed);

     if (in_array($sprequests_check,$row) !== false) {
        // adding anything to $reasons will cause submission to fail
         $reasons .= '|error';
      }
      if (in_array($theirname,$row) !== false) {
         $reasons .= '|error';
      }
      if (in_array($email,$row) !== false) {
         $reasons .= '|error';
      }
      if (in_array($phone,$row) !== false) {
         $reasons .= '|error';
      }
}
```

The current list of banned words is [here](https://www.laffstucson.com/index.php?page=spammmm)

Comment: What is the purpose of `$disallowed->bind_param('s', $Filter);`? Your query has no parameter placeholders in it

Comment: `strpos($sprequests,$disallowed);` makes no sense - $disallowed is your mysqli statement object and $sprequests doesn't seem to exist. What is this line for?

Comment: $sprequests is from the form 
```$sprequests = strip_tags($_POST['sprequests']);```

Guess I omitted a bunch. This is my first post here and I was kinda forced into editing all this.

Comment: Ok but you do need to ensure that what you provide is a [mre] of your issue, including relevant code and data needed to demonstrate the problem. Otherwise people will tend to get sidetracked looking at things that are undefined in your code, etc.

Comment: Does `nl_filters` just have one column in it? What is it called?

Comment: Thank you for your replies - missed the edit deadline

$sprequests is from the form:
`$sprequests = strip_tags($_POST['sprequests']);`

`$sprequests_check = strpos($sprequests,$disallowed);`

That was supposed to check $sprequests for any instance of a banned string.

@ADyson On this: What is the purpose of $disallowed->bind_param('s', $Filter);
Is that just missing a WHERE Filter=? 

Guess I omitted a bunch. This is my first post here and I was kinda forced into editing all this.

Comment: @ADyson `nl_filters` is one column, 'Filters'

Comment: Please don't put too much relevant information in comments, you can edit the question and add it there.

Comment: Also, welcome to the [Scunthorpe Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: There's no "edit deadline". The [edit] button is right there under your question. And yeah, Scunthorpe can be a problem. Essex and Middlesex can be tricky too, potentially. I'm sure with a bit of thought you can come up with plenty more

Comment: Why are you doing checks in your assignment? Assign all the data from the query to your disallowed words, then explode your input on ' ', and check if any of the words exist in your disallowed list. For words that contain disallowed words as a sub of the word, use regex and check for non-alpha characters either side of the word.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with for this problem uses the `$disallowed_terms` array to create a regex pattern that is then used to check each term in a users input.

We can check each term by first removing any special characters from the input and replace it with a space and then using explode to separate the string out into an array.

I simplified the code for the example so the `$disallowed_terms` is a static array and the inputs are also a static array. Feel free to modify the code to match your project.

I have left comments throughout the code explaining whats going on but if I missed something let me know :). See the code below:

```
<?php
// Example disallowed terms, you would get these from the database
$disallowed_terms = [
    "bad",
    "evil",
    "crazy"
];

//example inputs from the user
$inputs = [
    "I like bad   things",
    "I like good things",
    "I like ok things",
    "I like evil, things",
    "  I like-crazy.things ",
];

$disallowed_terms_pattern = create_disallowed_terms_regex($disallowed_terms); // get the regex that will be used
// echo $disallowed_terms_pattern; // Outputs: /(bad|evil|crazy)/

// Test each input from user and echo the result
foreach ($inputs as $input){

    if(contains_disallowed_term($input,$disallowed_terms_pattern)){ // call function to check if input contains disallowed term
       // disallowed term found
        echo "NOT GOOD -".$input."<br>";
    }else{
        // disallowed term NOT found
        echo "OK -". $input."<br>";
    }
}

/* SAMPLE OUTPUT:
    NOT GOOD -I like bad things
    OK -I like good things
    OK -I like ok things
    NOT GOOD -I like evil, things
    NOT GOOD - I like-crazy.things
*/

// create regex pattern string that will contain all the disallowed terms eg. Outputs: /(bad|evil|crazy)/
function create_disallowed_terms_regex($disallowed_terms){
    $regex = '/(';
    foreach ($disallowed_terms as $term){
        $regex.=$term.'|';
    }

    $regex = rtrim($regex,'|'); // remove | from end of string

    $regex .= ')/';

    return $regex;
}

function contains_disallowed_term($input,$disallowed_terms_pattern){

    // Replace all special characters with spaces, this stops inputs like i'am-not-crazy;) from getting passed the regex
    $input = preg_replace('/[^\w\s]/', ' ', $input);

    $input_terms = explode(" ", $input); // explode the input string into an array using spaces as a seperator

    foreach ($input_terms as $term){ // go over each term in the input
        if(preg_match($disallowed_terms_pattern, $term)){
            return true; // if it matches a word in disallowed list return true;
        }
    }
    
    //term didn't match disallowed term, return false
    return false;
}

?>
```

The obvious limitation to this solution is it won't be able to detect words like 'cr*zy' because it removes the * and replaces it with a space. On the flip side it will detect the word crazy in sting like this '.:thats-crazy:.'.

If some of the disallowed words contain special characters the solution may need modifaction as well. As the create_disallowed_terms_regex() function could break and words with special characters would never be detected because the solution strips special characters out of the input. Both issues can be mitigated with minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Here I used stripos() so the search is case-insensitive. you can get more info about stripos [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).
2. I also used $row['banned_words'] assuming banned_words is the column name in the database, instead of $disallowed (which is the actual query).

   ```
   <?php
   $disallowed_terms = array();
   $reasons = []; // Initialize $reasons

   // Fetch banned words from the database
   $disallowed = $database->connection->prepare("SELECT 
   banned_words FROM filtered_words");
   $disallowed->execute();

   $s_result = $disallowed->get_result();

   // check each input for banned words
   while ($row = $s_result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $disallowed_terms[] = $row['banned_words'];

       // Check if any banned words are present in each input
      checkAndAddError($_POST, 'sprequests', $disallowed_terms);
      checkAndAddError($_POST, 'theirname', $disallowed_terms);
      checkAndAddError($_POST, 'email', $disallowed_terms);
      checkAndAddError($_POST, 'phone', $disallowed_terms);
   }

   function containsBannedWord($input, $bannedWords) {
       $occurrences = array();

       foreach ($bannedWords as $bannedWord) {
           $pos = stripos($input, $bannedWord);
           while ($pos !== false) {
           $occurrences[] = array('word' => $bannedWord, 'position' => $pos);
           $pos = stripos($input, $bannedWord, $pos + 1);
           }
       }

       return $occurrences;
   }

   function checkAndAddError($inputArray, $fieldName, $bannedWords) {
       global $reasons;

       if (!is_array($reasons)) {
           $reasons = array();
       }

       if (isset($inputArray[$fieldName]) && is_string($inputArray[$fieldName])) {
           $occurrences = containsBannedWord($inputArray[$fieldName], $bannedWords);

           foreach ($occurrences as $occurrence) {
               $reasons[] = "Banned word '{$occurrence['word']}' found at position {$occurrence['position']} in '$fieldName'";
           }
       }
   }


   // Display form and results
   ?>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Banned Words Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

       <h1>Banned Words Test</h1>

       <form method="post">
           <label for="sprequests">sprequests:</label>
           <input type="text" name="sprequests" id="sprequests">
           <br>
           <label for="theirname">theirname:</label>
           <input type="text" name="theirname" id="theirname">
           <br>
           <label for="email">email:</label>
           <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
           <br>
           <label for="phone">phone:</label>
           <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
           <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
       </form>

    <?php
    // Display results
    echo '<h2>Results:</h2>';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST); // Display user inputs
    echo 'Reasons: ';
    print_r($reasons);
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
   ```

- The function'containsBannedWord' checks for banned words in a given input and returns an array containing occurrences along with their positions.
- The function 'checkAndAddError' checks each input field for banned words using the containsBannedWord function.
  If banned words are found, it adds error messages to the $reasons array.

  ```
    I tested with this inputs;
        [sprequests] => I will kill you crazy fool
        [theirname] => i hate you stupid
        [email] => fool@gmail.com
        [phone] => 2794
    Here is the reponse;
        [0] => Banned word 'crazy' found at position 16 in 'sprequests'
        [1] => Banned word 'stupid' found at position 11 in 'theirname'
        [2] => Banned word 'kill' found at position 7 in 'sprequests'
        [3] => Banned word 'fool' found at position 22 in 'sprequests'
        [4] => Banned word 'fool' found at position 0 in 'email'
        [5] => Banned word 'crazy' found at position 16 in 'sprequests'
        [6] => Banned word 'hate' found at position 2 in 'theirname'
  ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).